# PHP - use method chaining to extends previous method

Tags: php, method-chaining

how can i do additional method(such as Laravel), that extends previous in chaining ? 
For example: 
`$page->loadFooter()->withExtension("script_name")` where `withExtension()` is additional method, that affect result of `loadFooter()` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you return an object, typically `$this`

```
class Page {
    public $footer;
    public function loadFooter() {
        $this->footer = file_get_contents("footer.html");
        return $this;
    }
    public function withExtension($script) {
        $this->footer = str_replace($this->footer, "</body>", "<script src='{$script}'></script></body>");
    }
}

$page = new Page();
$page->loadFooter()->withExtension("script name");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has little problem. When I load footer with extension method it will looks like : `...</body></html><script src='script.js'></script>`, so that doesn't look great.

Comment: See the edit, this will put the script right before the closing body tag

Answer (score 1):

The way method chaining works is that each call has to return the object itself (i.e. `$this`).

So your page class definition would look like:

```
class Page {
    public function loadFooter() {
        /* ... */
        return $this;
    }

    public function withExtension($script) {
        /* ... */
        return $this;
    }
}
```

What's actually happening in method chaining is that the next function gets called on the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

`loadFooter()` just needs to return an object that has a `withExtension` method. So if you want to affect the `$page` object than `loadFooter` should return its object.

```
/*Within $page's class*/

public function loadFooter(){
  /**insert Code**/
  return $this;
}
```